# Grid is not rendering in DevExtreme ReacGrid

Tags: reactjs

Error Messaage is as follows:
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `LibrariesOfProduct`.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    PagingState,
    LocalPaging,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import {
    Grid,
    VirtualTableView,
    TableHeaderRow,
    TableColumnResizing,
    PagingPanel,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-bootstrap3';
import Chip from 'material-ui/Chip';
import LibrariesOfProd
    from '../../../services/dependencyManager/database/LoadProductLibraries';
import LoadingScreen from '../Common/LoadingScreen';

export default class LibrariesOfProduct extends React.PureComponent {
    /**
     * @class LibrariesOfProduct
     * @extends {Component}
     * @param {any} props props for constructor
     * @description Sample React component
     */
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tRows: [],
            showTable: false,
            columnWidths: {
                Count: 100,
                LibraryName: 400,
                LibraryVersion: 200,
                LibraryType: 200,
                LatestVersion: 300,
                GroupID: 200,
                ArtifactID: 200,
            },
            columns: [
                { name: 'Count', title: '' },
                { name: 'LibraryName', title: 'Library Name' },
                { name: 'LibraryType', title: 'Library Type' },
                { name: 'LibraryVersion', title: 'Current Version' },
                { name: 'LatestVersion', title: 'Latest Version' },
                { name: 'ArtifactID', title: 'Artifact ID' },
                { name: 'GroupID', title: 'Group ID' },
            ],
            prodName: '',
            prodVersion: '',
            numberOfRecords: 0,
        };
        this.loadTable = this.loadTable.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (props.renderCondition) {//eslint-disable-line
            this.setState({
                prodName: props.nameComp,//eslint-disable-line
                prodVersion: props.versionComp,//eslint-disable-line
                numberOfRecords: 0,
                showTable: false,
            });
            this.loadTable(props.nameComp, props.versionComp);
        }
    }
    /**
    * Load libraries of given Product
    */
    loadTable(pName, pVersion) {
        LibrariesOfProd.getLibrariesOfProduct(pName, pVersion).then((response) => {
            let i = 0;
            const array = [];
            if (response.Libraries.length > 0) {
                for (i; i < response.Libraries.length; i++) {
                    array[i] = {
                        Count: i + 1,
                        LibraryName: response.Libraries[i].LIB_NAME,
                        LibraryType: response.Libraries[i].LIB_TYPE,
                        LibraryVersion: response.Libraries[i].LIB_VERSION,
                        LatestVersion: response.Libraries[i].LATEST_VERSION,
                        GroupID: response.Libraries[i].ARTIFACT_ID,
                        ArtifactID: response.Libraries[i].GROUP_ID,
                    };
                }
            } else {
                array[0] = 'No results';
            }
            this.setState({
                tRows: array,
                numberOfRecords: response.Libraries.length,
                showTable: true,
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
        let returnView;
        const { tRows, columns } = this.state;//eslint-disable-line
        console.log(this.state.numberOfRecords);
        if (this.props.renderCondition) {
            if (this.state.showTable) {
                returnView = (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.numberOfRecords > 0 ?
                            <div>
                                <Chip>
                                    {this.state.numberOfRecords} results are returned
                                </Chip>
                                <Grid
                                    rows={tRows}
                                    columns={columns}
                                >
                                    <PagingState
                                        defaultCurrentPage={0}
                                        pageSize={12}
                                    />
                                    <LocalPaging />
                                    <VirtualTableView />
                                    <TableColumnResizing defaultColumnWidths={this.state.columnWidths} />
                                    <TableHeaderRow allowResizing />
                                    <PagingPanel />
                                </Grid>
                            </div>
                            :
                            <Chip>
                                No Libraries Found
                            </Chip>
                        }
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                returnView = (
                    <LoadingScreen />
                );
            }
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {returnView}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `LibrariesOfProduct`.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code where you get this error

Comment: I added it by editing it. Please check

Comment: Make sure all your imported files are coming properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the above error is that the version I am using is "1.0.0-beta.1" and it support 'TableView'. The problem is with versions used.